# How to calculate $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{ax+b}{\sqrt{cx^{2}+dx+e}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Please help to calculate this limit problem. I guess the result is $\frac{a}{\sqrt{c}}$.

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{ax+b}{\sqrt{cx^{2}+dx+e}}$$

where $a\neq 0$, $c\neq 0$, $d\neq 0$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673826/limit-of-sqrtx3-x-3-x-as-x-to-infty/1673948#1673948

Comment: Just take x out from the square root in the denominator, divide by x, and apply the limit

Comment: @Nikunj wow, excellent solution ! Thank you so much!

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notice that $c>0$, because
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}(cx^2+dx+e)=
\lim_{x\to+\infty}x^2\left(c+\frac{d}{x}+\frac{e}{x^2}\right)=
\begin{cases}
+\infty & \text{if $c>0$}\\[4px]
-\infty & \text{if $c<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
So the limit is not defined unless $c>0$. Granted this, you can do the substitution $x=1/t$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\dfrac{a}{t}+b}{\sqrt{\dfrac{c}{t^2}+\dfrac{d}{t}+e}}
=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{a+bt}{\sqrt{c+dt+et^2}}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Divide by $x$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\frac{a+\overbrace{b/x}^{\to 0}}{\sqrt{c+\underbrace{d/x}_{\to 0}+\underbrace{e/x^2}_{\to 0}}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt c}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the equivalents we obtain that $$ax+b\sim_{x\to +\infty} ax$$and $$
\sqrt{cx^{2}+dx+e}\sim_{x\to +\infty}\sqrt c x$$ therefore $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{ax+b}{\sqrt{cx^{2}+dx+e}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt c}$$